# Chrome memory allocation instrumentation on timeline inactive tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I have a very slow memory leak in my web application which I can easily reproduce by leaving the application opened over night.

I am trying now to isolate the leakage by using the Google Chrome "allocation instrumentation on timeline" under Developer Tools.

When the tab is active I see this:

[image]

When I change tab (so that the monitored tab is inactive):

[image]

And surprise... if I change back to that tab:

[image]

Why is the allocated memory getting completely unallocated only when the tab is active?

Is it possible that my application crash is caused by the above behaviour?

I'm trying to keep the application opened in an active tab at my office so tomorrow I'll find out but I am still wondering if this is a known Chrome behavior.